# How to filter mat card in angular

Tags: html, css, angular, filter, mat-card

I'm wondering how I can use the search bar(https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflowcom-a-60857864-6433166-dpaump ) and the code below to be able to filter the cards using it name.

This is my Explore TS file (I imported matcards and routers components from different files)

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { WorkspaceService } from 'src/app/core/services/workspace.service';
import { Workspace, WorkspaceType } from 'src/app/shared/models/workspace.model';
```

And this is inside HTML file to display the cards

```
 <mc-workspace-card-list [workspaces] = "pubWorkspaces" [editable] = "false"></mc-workspace-card-list>
```

And this is what it look like right now

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

> Note: I did not included the code above in my Stackblitz file because there are alot of components involved 
>   and I'm wondering if someone can help me or give me tips on how to implement this filter function for cards by just looking the code above and stackblitz file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Citrus punk's answer works but here is some explanation

HTML:

```
<input type="text"
[(ngModel)]="searchText" (ngModelChange)="searchTextChanged($event)" />
```

Ts:

In ngOnInit After this forEach store copy pubWorkspaces in separate array

```
   workspaces.forEach(workspace => {
        if(workspace.type == WorkspaceType.public){
          this.pubWorkspaces.push(workspace);
        }
      });
   this.filteredPubWorkSpaces= this.pubWorkspaces;
```

Below  function gets called when there is change in search and im assuming you have name property in pubws object.

```
searchTextChanged(searchText){
 //return array of workspace only having search text in their names
  this.filteredPubWorkSpaces= this.pubWorkspaces.filter(pubws=>pubws.name.includes(searchText));
}
```

Pass it to component

```
 `<mc-workspace-card-list [workspaces] = "filteredPubWorkSpaces" [editable] = "false"></mc-workspace-card-list>`
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm not sure about the input. I'm getting Property 'searchText' does not exist on type 'ExploreComponent'. Can you use the same input filter from stackblitz file since I'll be filtering Mat Chip and Mat Card at the same time.

Comment: create searchText' in the properties section inside ts like searchText:string

Comment: pubWorkspaces: Workspace[] = [];
  loading: boolean = false; after this  searchText:string

Answer (score 1):

You could make an additional list that is showing the results.
Just copy the full list when initializing the component. On the searchbar change event you can call a function that filters the original list with the searchterm and save this to an extra variable:

```
export class ExploreComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

private workspaces;
public filteredWorkspaces;
public searchterm;

constructor(private workspaceService: WorkspaceService, private router: Router) { }


ngOnInit(): void {

    this.loading = true;
    this.workspaceService.getUserWorkspaces().subscribe((workspaces) =>{

    workspaces.forEach(workspace => {
      if(workspace.type == WorkspaceType.public){
        this.pubWorkspaces.push(workspace);
      }
    this.filteredWorkspaces = workspaces;
}

onInputChange(){
    this.filteredWorkspaces = this.workspaces.filter(ws => ws.name.includes(this.searchterm));
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm not really understand what you are saying. I tried to follow as best as I can but still not working out. if you can help me with step by step, that'll be grateful.

Comment: Thank You CitrusPunk for your help.